# Table creation in Databricks with alias column name

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, create-table, databricks-sql

HI I recently started exploring databricks,I got following issue

I am creating delta table but I want to give alias name to the column how can i give this. I tried with this approach but its not working

create or replace table gen1 (ID int, name string as tata)

I got following error

```
mismatched input 'as' expecting {')', ',', 'CONSTRAINT'}(line 1, pos 40)
```

== SQL ==

```
create  table gen1 (ID int, name string as EmpName )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as alias for a column name - aliases are used primarily when you doing `select`, etc.  In your case, just give the column correct name directly: `create  table gen1 (ID int, EmpName string)`